# PHPStorm keeps opening Firefox by default when running

Tags: phpstorm

I want PHPStorm to run my default browser - Internet explorer... and yet it runs Firefox.

- I have unticked all options in the settings/web browsers and left only IE ticked.
- I have changed my run application options to internet explorer (under edit configuration)

It keeps running Firefox or comes up with cannot find chrome...  There's a good reason for that, I don't have it installed...

What am I missing in the set up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2nd screenshot is for Defaults and not for actual Run/Debug configuration. Plus, it's for PHP code (is that what you want to run?). Show me the actual Run/Debug configuration that you are using.

Comment: ah, thanks for saying that.. I realised you can actually add a PHP Web application into the list and now it works. Phew...

Comment: Just curious, What did you do to make it open with ie?

Comment: I had to actually add a PHP web application to the list... Using the green plus button shown in the bottom picture. Don't use the default part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your 2nd screenshot shows that you making changes to Defaults and not actual Run/Debug Configuration.
2. What kind of page (job) you are trying to open (do): works with JavaScript or some PHP page?

   You are making changes to default for "PHP Web Application" but at the same time you have 1 temp configuration of "JavaScript Debug" type which only supports Chrome for the moment (hence the *"or comes up with cannot find chrome..."* part)

Therefore please create Run/Debug Configuration of correct type, configure and use it. If still not working -- show it here.